# C# extension method to objects with specific attribute

Tags: serialization, extension-methods

I created an extension method that will tell me the size of every object I create
like this:

```
public static int CalculateKilobytes(this object notSuspectingCandidate)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, notSuspectingCandidate);
        return stream.ToArray().Count() / 1000;
    }
}
```

Since I'm using serializaion, not all objects will be able to return answer, only the serializble ones. Is there a way to attach this method to an object that can be serialized?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Type.IsSerializable Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isserializable.aspx).

```
public static int CalculateKilobytes(this object notSuspectingCandidate)
    {          
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                if (notSuspectingCandidate.GetType().IsSerializable) {
                    formatter.Serialize(stream, notSuspectingCandidate);
                    return stream.ToArray().Count() / 1000;
                }
                return 0;
            }         
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick response, i have several ways to prevent exception (also with try/catch). I'm hoping for preventing the extension method from appearing to objects that are not serializable in compile time

Answer (score 0):

It's a really bad practice to serialize a object only to get its size, if you plan to serialize it again later.

**Use with caution.**

The extension method will be applied to all objects, you must check if it has the custom property in it.

This check can do the job.

```
if (notSuspectingCandidate.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SerializableAttribute), true).Length == 0)
{
    return -1; // An error
}
```

Another way is to put a extension method to ISerializable and use the interface in all your required types.

```
public static int CalculateKilobytes(this ISerializable notSuspectingCandidate)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, notSuspectingCandidate);
        return stream.ToArray().Count() / 1000;
    }
}
```